Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: port error getting while executing through testng
enter image description here
Please help me how to reslove above error
I am trying to launch chrome browser using testing frame work but getting above error message
Scenario is just trying to automate login scenario using page object model concept

please check and consider Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

You might want to watch this issue https://github.com/testng-team/testng-remote/issues/186

In Eclipse Go to Help >> Eclipse Marketplace >> Installed tab. Make sure that 'TestNG for Eclipse' plugin is installed. In case you see 'update' button in front of already installed  plugin then make sure to update the plugin. Restart the Eclipse and you are good to go.

I have resolved this issue by making sure POM dependency version should match with Eclipse testNG version
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>7.9.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>



I have resolve this issue eclipse testNG version
Click help>>About>Installation detail>select TestNG and Update

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
